# Using awk mktime to transform datetime fields to Epoch in cvs

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

I have a csv file which contanins about 6 milion , seperated lines

```
    1,2018-11-25 23:00:26,403,74
    1,2018-11-25 23:02:10,406,68
    1,2018-11-25 23:04:19,448,108
    1,2018-11-25 23:05:26,417,79
    1,2018-11-25 23:05:30,378,80
    1,2018-11-25 23:05:31,360,78
    1,2018-11-25 23:06:45,391,79
    1,2018-11-25 23:06:50,432,76
```

These times are UTC, I am living in Europe UTC + 1. I've 'written' my first AWK script: test.awk:

```
    BEGIN { FS=",";OFS="\t"}
    {
        $2 = mktime(gensub(/[-:]/,"  ","g",$2))

        print
    }
```

When I run:

```
      $ awk -f test.awk mark.csv
```

It gives the output:

```
    1   1543183226  403 74
    1   1543183330  406 68
    1   1543183459  448 108
    1   1543183526  417 79
    1   1543183530  378 80
    1   1543183531  360 78
    1   1543183605  391 79
    1   1543183610  432 76
```

Looks ok, but the problem is the epoch is one hour early

```
    1543183226≠2018-11-25 23:00:26 but 1543183226=2018-11-25 22:00:26
```

To solve this problem I am looking at

```
    strftime([format [, timestamp[, utc-flag]]])
```

I am almost there but I could use some help.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just set the timezone (`TZ`) variable to `UTC` before calling awk or set the UTC flag for mktime():

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{print mktime("2018 11 25 23 00 26")}'
1543208426

$ TZ=UTC awk 'BEGIN{print mktime("2018 11 25 23 00 26")}'
1543186826

$ awk 'BEGIN{print mktime("2018 11 25 23 00 26",1)}'
1543186826

$ awk 'BEGIN{print mktime("2018 11 25 22 00 26",1)}'
1543183226
```

Comment: that simpel, great answer, this solves my problem, Thank you

Answer (score 1):

***EDIT:*** Taking reference from Ed sir's code and applying in this code.

```
TZ=UTC awk '
BEGIN{
  FS=","
  OFS="\t"
}
{
  $2 = mktime(gensub(/[-:]/,"  ","g",$2))
  print $2
}'  Input_file
```

---

---

Could you please try following. Since 1 hour has 3600 seconds, so what I did is while sending $2's value to `strftime` I subtracted this to its value and we got 1 hour earlier value (this approach is not be flexible, one should use above code only).

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  FS=","
  OFS="\t"
}
{
  $2 = mktime(gensub(/[-:]/,"  ","g",$2))
  print strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",$2-3600)
}'  Input_file
```

First line's output will be `2018-11-25 22:00:26` now.

Comment: @fasln01, Sorry your comment is not completed, I thought post says time should be 1 hour lesser?

Comment: I am looking for the correct epoch time, the first line should look like this:
 1   1543186826  403 74 where the epoch time corresponds with the first line of the original file 1,2018-11-25 23:00:26,403,74 datetime

Comment: 1543186826 == 2018-11-25 23:00:26

Comment: I want to convert datetime to the Epoch time

Comment: @fasln01,but that you have done already? Sorry I am getting confuse now :(

Comment: This approach won't work robustly due to DST in the OPs timezone adjusting the time difference vs UTC.